# PowerBI concatatenate 3 tables

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to concatenate 3 different tables in powerBI, with powerQuery but I couldn't find the solution for it. The closest I could find is appending the query, however it does not concatenate the table shown below.

Example:

[image: concatenate table example and result]

Im trying to concatenate table Code1 to Code2 to Code3 (bottom 3 tables) to look like the top one.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: There is no Code ```003``` in your sample input tables, but there is in your output table.  How did that get there?

Comment: Hey Jody, sorry that was a typo. It should just be 001 and 002 s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom column to each of your queries, all with the same value.  For my test I just used the value of `1`.

[image]

Then merge Query 1 to Query 2 on your custom column.  Next, merge that query to Query 3 again on the custom column.  Once you rearrange the columns you will get an output that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method

In Table3, add column, custom column,

```
= Table1
```

then expand

Add column, custom column

```
= Table2
```

then expand