# Creating a VBA script to copy and paste a cell into a range of cells from multiple sources

Tags: excel, vba

Incredibly new to trying VBA. I want to take the following data and connect each row with data from another sheet. Basically I want each row of the initial list below to correspond with every location range from the second list. I'd like to know how to make it do it for any number of rows from the first list, as long as there is data in the row.

Initial List

[image]

Location list

[image]

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect the lists to each other you need a reference column in both lists.

In the “simplest way” using the cell function “vlookup” or “xlookup” to pull over desired columns from one list to another based on the matching value of the respective reference columns.

For more “advanced way” of connecting tables you may want to use “joins” in PowerQuery.

If you want to add the same initial list for each of the locations, in VBA you can loop through the locations and add the cell range of the initial list each time.

Or like this with PowerQuery:

[PowerBI concatatenate 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72469504/powerbi-concatatenate-3-tables/72475397#72475397)